# Concat two observables into one observable so that values get fired on one observable only

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I want to join two observables of type `T[]` returned from httpservice.

I tried forkjoin and zip but they return an Observable of type `[T[], T[]]` and I want to return an object of type `T[]` as shown in the code below.
Is there a way to do that in angular 7?

Please help I need this for my work.

```js
public getSelectFlux(value): Observable<SelectAutocompleteModel[]> {
  if (!this.isFluxAuto) {
    return forkJoin(this.selectAutoCompleteService.selectedFlux(
      this.getInstance(value, false)), this.selectAutoCompleteService.selectedFlux(this.getInstance(value, true)));
  }
  return this.selectAutoCompleteService.selectedFlux(this.getInstance(value, false));
}
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do but there are a lot of more methods in rxjs maybe combineLatest sound more like something that could be used here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: very unclear question... `Observable <[T[], T[]]>>` is of type `Observable`

Comment: i want to get Observable< T[] > + Observable< T[] > =  Observable< T[] > and zip and forkjoin return an Observable < [ T[] , T[] ] > not what i want

Answer (score 1):

You need a [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) operator. Merge operator will merge two observables and will return single observable on which both observable values will get fired.

Your code will look like:

```js
public getSelectFlux(value): Observable<SelectAutocompleteModel[]> {
  if (!this.isFluxAuto) {
    return merge(
      this.selectAutoCompleteService.selectedFlux(this.getInstance(value, false)),
      this.selectAutoCompleteService.selectedFlux(this.getInstance(value, true))
    )
  }
  return this.selectAutoCompleteService.selectedFlux(this.getInstance(value, false));
}
```